# How is reputation calculated on heavily edited posts?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm asking purely out of curiosity. I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51920498/4700841) on the main SO and the linked answer (when combined with comments) helped me to solve my problem:

> Instead of using Namespace.GetDefaultFolder, use
>   Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder, passing a Recipient object returned
>   from Namespace.CreateRecipient.
>
> Also keep in mind that looping through all items in a folder is a
>   horrible idea, especially if you open an online folder not cached in a
>   local OST file. Use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict instead.

However, in order to maximise the benefit to future users I plan on heavily editing the answer to include well explained sample code etc. etc. rather than just method names.

I'm not particularly bothered but it seems to me as though there should be some proportional split in the reputation gained from this answer due to the fact that two parties have spent time and effort writing and improving the answer.

This may already be in place. If it is, how exactly is this calculated? It seems to me as though there would have to be some sort of "edit effort" metric to avoid people gaming rep by making simple, meaningless edits.

That being said, if someone is adding such substantial content should they make it a separate answer? Although this seems dishonest given that the short-form answer helped them solve their issue.

---

**Edit:** Thanks to everyone who commented/answered, due to the substantial amount of new content, I created my own answer and referenced the original.

Comment: Edits aren't meant to significantly change how an answer was written. Why wouldn't you add a answer if your answer is that different? You only get 2 rep from an accepted edit, up to a cap of 2k total rep / 1k from edits. That's all you get out of  suggesting edits.

Comment: It's impossible for a system to determine the effort of an edit. Sometimes a small edit make an answer better. By the way you should avoid heavy edits

Comment: There's no such split in place, you'll get `+2` from the edit and the feeling of having given something back after getting help to solve your problem. That's really it. SO tried to give points to editors with the documentation experiment and it lead to a massive amount of silly edits on popular posts since everyone seemed to want a piece of the action. There's nothing wrong with writing a new, more detailed answer and reference the original to give credit/attribution.

Comment: The intention would be to add clarification and expand on the existing answer

Comment: Well I guess that settles that. As I said, I'm not bothered about the rep I was just wondering what the "best practice" in instances such as this is considered to be. Cheers guys :)

Comment: Also not sure why the question is getting downvoted... What's inherently wrong with the question?

Comment: *avoid people gaming rep by making simple, meaningless edits* - There's a Suggested Edit Review Queue were edits from users under 2K rep get reviewed by users with 2K rep or more. Meaningless edits are (supposed to be) rejected, along with harmful or destructive edits.

Comment: @Persistence: "*Also not sure why the question is getting downvoted... What's inherently wrong with the question?*" Within the text of your question, you admitted to preparing to do something that is very much frowned upon: radically editing someone else's post. That kind of thing tends to attract downvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be posting your own separate answer if you want to add your own original content.  If others think that your answer is better, they can upvote it.

Edits are there to improve an existing answer, not to edit your own new answer into it.

Given that all of the underlying content is the original author's, all reputation from votes on the post goes to them, not the editors.

The one exception is Community Wiki posts.  These are posts that are collaborative works of multiple people, and are expected to be edited to make substantive changes to the underlying content of the answer, not just its presentation.  Because there's no real way of knowing how much of the usefulness of the post comes from each of the editors, CW posts don't earn any rep at all.